# Trigger windows button background color change on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecellrenderer

I have a Swing application with Windows look and feel, and I'm having hard times with a JComboBox. When clicking on it, the default Windows button color change feature works properly (that well-known Windows icy blue color).

However, when I click the neighboring field, its color won't change. It is a custom table with the two columns wired together, the colour change feauture works perfectly with JTextFields.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (column == 0 || !isSelected || !table.hasFocus()) {
        combobox.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        combobox.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    } else {
        if (isSelected && table.hasFocus()) {
            combobox.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            combobox.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }
    }
    combobox.setFont(table.getFont());
    combobox.getModel().setSelectedItem(value == null ? "" : value.toString());
    return combobox;
}
```

Now this does not work. When I click on the neighbouring textfield the isSelected && table.hasFocus block gets executed however the colour of the combo box remains the same. The value of

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().get("Button.background");
```

remains [240; 240; 240] even when I click directly on the combo box and its colour becomes icy blue.

How can I trigger the Windows icy blue colour?

Comment: perhaps providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would get more responses. IMO I do not have the time to go and code a full working SSCCE attempting to re-enact your problem than still to fix it.